# Как проверить, есть ли элемент с классом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    search = soup.find('span', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    return span.text, search.text

    if search is None:
        search = soup.find('span', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    else:
        search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
```

Нужно спарсить инфу с двух видов url, на одном нужная инфа есть в тэге div с классом `'search-total js-search-total'` а в другом есть тэг span с тем же классом - `'search-total js-search-total'`

Нужно проверять, имеется ли на странице тэг div или тэг span с одним и тем же классом, и если есть, то `search =`

Всю документацию BS4 от корки до корки прочёл, но так и не нашёл нужного мне ответа.

Comment: Но это же элементарно.  `if search is None: элемента нет else элемент еcть`

Comment: дело в том, что я пробовал сделать так, но по всей видимости не правильно, т.к. ошибка: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    search = soup.find('span', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    if (search is None):
        search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    return span.text, search.text
```

Работает таким образом.